# Where can I find Mojave Kernel Headers?

Tags: development, kernel, mojave

I'm trying to get a hold of the Kernel Headers for 10.14 Mojave, but even though the Beta version (even two actually) was already released, XNU's repository (both [here](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu) and [here](https://opensource.apple.com/)) is still only up-to-date with High Sierra.

I also tried getting Command Line Developer Tools but they only contain User Headers (and maybe a few but not a lot of Kernel Headers).

Anything else I could do? I don't really need the Kernel source as a whole, only its headers.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently XCode command line tools doesn't install the headers by default anymore. However, it does provide a package in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages`. On my system it was `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`. I installed this package and then the headers showed up in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Headers`.

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing else you can do except contact Apple.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/239952)

Comment: @MelvinJefferson You're incorrect. It does indeed answer the question "Anything else I could do". There is absolutely nothing the requester can do besides contacting Apple. Which most probably won't be fruitful unless he already has an existing business relationship with Apple regarding these matters. Apple is known for not releasing the kernel source code "early" at all. There's no need to critique or request clarification from the author as the question is to the point and clear.

Comment: Its more so a comment since the requestor is asking for what else he can do about getting the kernel headers for Mojave.

Comment: No, it’s actually not a comment. It is literally answering the question. Contact Apple is the only thing he can do at this point.

Comment: How is it legal for Apple to not release kernel source code for an OSS kernel at the same time they release new macOS versions (binaries)?

Comment: How would it be illegal? Apple writes the source code - they determine if and when they want to share the source code with others.